# What's the difference between set<pair> and map in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, dictionary, set

There are two ways in which I can easily make a key,value attribution in C++ STL: maps and sets of pairs. For instance, I might have

```
map<key_class,value_class>
```

or

```
set<pair<key_class,value_class> >
```

In terms of algorithm complexity and coding style, what are the differences between these usages?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask about multimap rather than map?

Comment: @RobKennedy: Perhaps you meant multiset and multimap...

Comment: Not at the time, @Einpoklum. I meant that in order to use a map to hold all the same values as a `set<pair>` can hold, you'd need the map to be a `multimap`. What I didn't consider was that to hold all the values a `multimap` can hold, you'd in turn need the set to be a `multiset<pair>`. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Set elements cannot be modified while they are in the set. `set`'s `iterator` and `const_iterator` are equivalent. Therefore, with `set<pair<key_class,value_class> >`, you cannot modify the `value_class` in-place. You must remove the old value from the set and add the new value. However, if `value_class` is a pointer, this doesn't prevent you from modifying the object it points to.

With `map<key_class,value_class>`, you can modify the `value_class` in-place, assuming you have a non-const reference to the map.

Answer (score 48):

They are *semantically* different. Consider:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  pair<int, int> p1(1, 1);
  pair<int, int> p2(1, 2);
  set< pair<int, int> > s;
  s.insert(p1);
  s.insert(p2);
  map<int, int> m;
  m.insert(p1);
  m.insert(p2);
  cout << "Set size = " << s.size() << endl;
  cout << "Map size = " << m.size() << endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/cZ8Vjr

Output:

> Set size = 2
>   Map size = 1

Comment: Would be even more complete to post also the resulting output + 1-line insight. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: map allows no duplicates of the key

Comment: If you replace the set declaration with this code then also the set doesn't allow duplicated keys:
`auto less_than = [](pair<int, int> p1, pair<int, int> p2) { return p1.first < p2.first; };
set< pair<int, int>, decltype(less_than) > s(less_than);`

Comment: Map sort according to the key value and duplicated keys are not allowed. But Set are allowed duplicated keys if only values are difference.

Comment: But if a set uses a custom comparator function that only compares the first field of the pair, they are equivalent (apart from const-ness) right?

Answer (score 12):

`map<key_class,value_class>` will sort on key_class and allow no duplicates of key_class.
`set<pair<key_class,value_class> >` will sort on key_class and then value_class if the  key_class instances are equal, and will allow multiple values for key_class

Answer (score 9):

The basic difference is that for the set the key is the pair, whereas for the map the key is key_class - this makes looking things up by key_class, which is what you want to do with maps, difficult for the set.

Both are typically implemented with the same data structure (normally  a red-black balanced binary tree), so the complexity for the two should be the same.

Comment: I can use lower_bound and upper_bound to find a value the set.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` acts as an associative data structure. In other words, it allows you to query and modify values using its associated key.

A `std::set<pair<K,V> >` can be made to work like that, but you have to write extra code for the query using a key and more code to modify the value (i.e. remove the old pair and insert another with the same key and a different value). You also have to make sure there are no more than two values with the same key (you guessed it, more code).

In other words, you can try to shoe-horn a `std::set` to work like a `std::map`, but there is no reason to.

Comment: indeed, I would just use std::map then  : p

Comment: I used a set<pair> instead of a multimap to efficiently find/remove key-values. With multimap I need two iterators and the inner iterator is O(m).

Answer (score 1):

To understand algorithmic complexity, you first need to understand the implementation.

std::map is implemented using RB-tree where as hash_map are implemented using arrays of linked list. std::map provides O(log(n)) for insert/delete/search operation, hash_map is O(1) is best case and o(n) in worst case depending upon hash collisions.

Comment: what's `hash_map`?  isn't the question about comparing `map` with `set`, not `map` with `hash_map`?

Comment: by *hash_map*, @sach is referring to *unordered_map*

Answer (score 1):

Visualising that semantic difference Philipp mentioned after stepping through the code, note how map key is a const int and how p2 was not inserted into **m**:

[image]